# Ionic timepicker limit results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using [ionic datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) and all I want from it is to get `hours,minutes,seconds` but I get result such as this `2020-10-05T00:00:27.634+07:00` what I need from this result is only `00:00:27`.

**My question is how to limit the result to my preferred version?**

## Code

```
<ion-datetime display-format="HH:mm:ss" picker-format="HH:mm:ss" formControlName="quiz_time"></ion-datetime>
```

**Note** this tag `<ion-datetime>` is ionic default and I did not add anything additional in component for running it, therefore there is nothing more than this to share with you, but what I obviously need is to add some functionality into my component in order to limit results of this input and that's what I'm asking help for.

`component`

Sending data to back-end

```
quizCreate() {
    const sems = this.quizData.value;
    this.quizService.quizCreate(
        sems.quiz_time, // my input (2020-10-05T00:00:27.634+07:00)
    ).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data.message);
      },
      error => {
        //
      },
      () => {
        //
      }
    );
}
```

**any idea?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Here is my final code that solved my problem

```
quizCreate() {
    const sems = this.quizData.value;

    // convert coming time
    const d = new Date(Date.parse(sems.quiz_time)); // my input (2020-10-05T00:00:27.634+07:00)
    // add second digits
    const hours = ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2);
    const minutes = ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    const seconds = ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    // join times
    const quizTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    this.quizService.quizCreate(
        sems.quiz_time = quizTime, // send joined time (00:00:27)
    ).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data.message);
      },
      error => {
        //
      },
      () => {
        //
      }
    );
}
```

Hope it can help others.